Access ssm parameter store parameters in cross account
I have my ssm parameter store set up in one of the aws account (account Source). I want to access the parameters in another aws account (account target). Earlier parameter store did not directly allow to share parameter in cross account. I came across this article that says now paramter store can access parameters in cross account using Resource access manager

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2024/02/aws-systems-manager-parameter-store-cross-account-sharing/#:~:text=To%20share%20parameters%2C%20you%20add,see%20Working%20with%20shared%20parameters.

I have added my parameter in RAM in Source account and gave target account execution role permissions to access this parameter.
Now i need to fetch the parameters programatically.
def fetch_parameters(key):
    ssm_client = build_client(service="ssm", region=get_aws_region())
    result = ssm_client.get_parameters(Names=[ARN], WithDecryption=True))
    return result["Parameters"][0]["Value"]

I'm executing this code from Target account and getting the following error:
IndexError: list index out of range
Can someone please guide on what's missing. Thanks!

Check your result for the error message or what you got back from the client call. There seems to Parameters list given back, thats why you are getting an index error.
As I am seeing you are using encryption make sure you also have the permissions on the encryption key etc.
Maybe you want to check the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/parameter-store-shared-parameters.html#prereqs

Thanks for your comment. I see in the doc to share kms customer key - Can you please guide if this is what you mean and what should be done for this?

On printing the results like you said I'm getting invalid parameters
result:{'Parameters': [], 'InvalidParameters': [''], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Thu, 04 Jul 2024 15:02:35 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '116', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': ''}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
